# React 17.0.2 complaining about react-select 2.4.3 version

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Trying to upgrade a react project from react 16 to react 17 but I am facing issue with `react-input-autosize@2.2.2` when I checked package.json `react-input-autosize@2.2.2` is not there then I found its linked inside `react-select2.4.3` which is in package.json so I need to know how to solve this. which `react-select` version I have to use for react 17.0.2

stack trace:

```
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: react-input-autosize@2.2.2
npm WARN Found: react@17.0.2
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   dev react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm WARN   17 more (@fortawesome/react-fontawesome, @material-ui/core, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^0.14.9 || ^15.3.0 || ^16.0.0-rc || ^16.0" from react-input-autosize@2.2.2
npm WARN node_modules/react-input-autosize
npm WARN   react-input-autosize@"^2.2.1" from react-select@2.4.4
npm WARN   node_modules/react-select
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"^0.14.9 || ^15.3.0 || ^16.0.0-rc || ^16.0" from react-input-autosize@2.2.2
npm WARN   node_modules/react-input-autosize
npm WARN     react-input-autosize@"^2.2.1" from react-select@2.4.4
npm WARN     node_modules/react-select
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: react-select@2.4.4
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   dev react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.x" from @fortawesome/react-fontawesome@0.1.19
npm ERR!   node_modules/@fortawesome/react-fontawesome
npm ERR!     @fortawesome/react-fontawesome@"^0.1.16" from the root project
npm ERR!   16 more (@material-ui/core, @material-ui/icons, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^15.3.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-select@2.4.4
npm ERR! node_modules/react-select
npm ERR!   react-select@"^2.4.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^15.3.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-select@2.4.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-select
npm ERR!     react-select@"^2.4.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
```

tried to upgrade versions for react from 16 to 17. looking to find out the dependency correct versions